# inserting a node after a specific node in xml file

Tags: c#, xmlnode

i'm re posting my question in a simpler way.

i need to search for a specific node in a XML file, and once i see it, i need to create a new node and insert it after that. the problem is that there are 2 nodes with the same value. and i need to insert the new node twice after each instance. with the code below: it's inserting the new nodes twice but in the same place after the first instance only.

original XML:

```
<eventlist>
  <event type="AUDIOPLAYER">
    <properties>
      <schedule startType="-ParentEnd1" />
      <media mediaType="Audio" />
    </properties>
  </event>
  <event type="AUDIOPLAYER">
    <properties>
      <schedule startType="-ParentEnd2" />
      <media mediaType="Audio" />
    </properties>
  </event>
</eventlist>
```

intended XML:

```
<eventlist>
  <event type="AUDIOPLAYER">
    <properties>
      <schedule startType="-ParentEnd1" />
      <media mediaType="Audio" />
    </properties>
  </event>
  <event type="VIZ" />
  <event type="AUDIOPLAYER">
    <properties>
      <schedule startType="-ParentEnd2" />
      <media mediaType="Audio" />
    </properties>
  </event>
    <event type="VIZ" />
</eventlist>
```

but the current output is:

```
<eventlist>
  <event type="AUDIOPLAYER">
    <properties>
      <schedule startType="-ParentEnd1" />
      <media mediaType="Audio" />
    </properties>
  </event>
  <event type="VIZ" />
  <event type="VIZ" />
  <event type="AUDIOPLAYER">
    <properties>
      <schedule startType="-ParentEnd2" />
      <media mediaType="Audio" />
    </properties>
  </event>
</eventlist>
```

the code is below here:

```
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(@"C:\Users\namokhtar\Desktop\newxml\testxml.xml");

    foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc.SelectNodes("/eventlist/event[@type='AUDIOPLAYER']"))
    {
        XmlNode srcNode = node.SelectSingleNode("/eventlist/event[@type='AUDIOPLAYER']");
        XmlNode newElem = xdoc.CreateElement("event");
        XmlAttribute newAttr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("type");
        newAttr.Value = "VIZ";
        newElem.Attributes.Append(newAttr);
        srcNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newElem, srcNode);
    }

    xdoc.Save(@"C:\Users\namokhtar\Desktop\newxml\newxml1.xml");
```

please advise me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven´t fully tested this, but I´m almost sure this should do the trick:

```
            foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc.SelectNodes("/eventlist/event[@type='AUDIOPLAYER']"))
            {
                XmlNodeList srcNodes = node.SelectNodes("/eventlist/event[@type='AUDIOPLAYER']");
                foreach (XmlNode srcNode in srcNodes)
                {

                    XmlNode newElem = xdoc.CreateElement("event");
                    XmlAttribute newAttr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("type");
                    newAttr.Value = "VIZ";
                    newElem.Attributes.Append(newAttr);
                    srcNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newElem, srcNode);
                }
            }
```

The problem is you were selecting single node from matching expression, and you need to select all the nodes that match that and insert the new node after each of them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are right, but i had to remove the first foreach loop. because it created the node twice. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using LINQ:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\namokhtar\Desktop\newxml\testxml.xml"));
var elems = xml.Root.Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name == "event" && e.Attribute("type")?.Value == "AUDIOPLAYER");

foreach (var elem in elems)
{
    elem.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("event", new XAttribute("type", "VIZ")));
}

xml.Save(@"C:\Users\namokhtar\Desktop\newxml\newxml1.xml");
```